# Silverlight 4 - Exception handling logic reuse when calling WCF proxy

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

I added a service reference to a silverlight app. When I want to call a method in the service I use those lines :

```
        CustomServiceClient proxy = new CustomServiceClient();
        proxy.GetDataCompleted += new EventHandler<GetDataCompletedEventArgs>(Proxy_GetDataCompleted);
        try
        {
            proxy.GetDataAsync(appUser.Id);
            proxy.CloseAsync();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", exception.GetType());
            proxy.Abort();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", exception.GetType());
            proxy.Abort();
        }
```

The problem is that every time I need to call a method I am duplicating this code. I can't figure out an elegant way to reuse it (I can use inheritance and make a new class for each method, but it's very ugly).

Comment: What's common and what's different each time?

Comment: It might help if the code example made sense to start with.  You can't encapsulate errors like timeout which will happen asynchronously with a try..catch block.

Comment: @jv42 What is common is everything, what is different is only the name of the method and maybe the Args object

Comment: @AnthonyWJone Ok, so ignore the TimeoutException. Lets say there are other exceptions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for something [similar to what is described in this CodeProject article.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightExceptions.aspx)

Comment: I tried looking at your link, but I can't see how this can help me. I am not throwing my own exceptions, but trying to catch network exceptions.

Comment: Right, you want common code to handle faults/exceptions thrown by the WCF service called from a Silverlight app. The section entitled "How do we fix this issue?" explains what the library intends to achieve. It has a service side component that handles actually invoking the service operations so special exception handling can be injected. On the client side, there is a proxy wrapper for invoking the WCF service which also contains special exception handling code. If you don't want to commit to this approach, it could be sample for basing your client side common exception handling code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in [this msdn forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/f5168400-8a84-4352-9a09-56077475ccc5/) seems to have an elegant solution to this by using extension methods.